# Replacing multiple occurrences of a value in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, replace

I have a vector of values

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

which I would like to replace with the values in vector y for EACH occurrence:

```
y <- c(8,9,11,24,56)
```

so that when I test this on a vector such as

```
z <- (1,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,2,3,2,3,4)
```

I get back z now equal to

```
z <- (8,9,11,24,56,24,11,24,9,11,9,11,24)
```

Comment: How about `y[z]` if `z` is holding position matches

Answer (score 5):

You can use function `match` to find matches between `z` and `x` and use them for indexing of `y`:

```
y[match(z,x)]
# [1]  8  9 11 24 56 24 11 24  9 11  9 11 24
```

Comment: Or `y[findInterval(z,x)]`

Comment: @akrun, that's a nice idea about `findInterval`, but it requires a non-decreasing order of  `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Richard Scriven's comment works so long as your `x` vector just counts from 1 to N.
For a more general solution, you'll want to reference `y` by `x` .

```
unlist(sapply(z, function(j) y[which(j==x)]))
```

EDIT: time trials:
(But keep in mind that `findInterval` will fail if `x` is not monotonic)

```
x <- 1:100
y <- sample(1:150,100,rep=TRUE)
z <- sample(1:100,300,rep=TRUE)

carl<-function(z,y,x) unlist(sapply(z, function(j) y[which(j==x)]))
marat<-function(z,y,x) y[match(z,x)]
akrun <- function(z,y,x) y[findInterval(z,x)]
microbenchmark(carl(z,y,x),marat(z,y,x),akrun(z,y,x),times=10)
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
  carl(z, y, x) 966.181 979.116 1088.7465 995.981 1090.096 1661.516    10
 marat(z, y, x)  17.888  18.600   23.9291  19.638   24.879   50.251    10
 akrun(z, y, x)  24.823  25.602   40.2708  26.897   29.375  159.849    10
 cld
   b
  a 
  a
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `fmatch` from `library(fastmatch)`

```
library(fastmatch)
y[fmatch(z,x)]
#[1]  8  9 11 24 56 24 11 24  9 11  9 11 24
```

#### Benchmarks

Using a slightly bigger dataset,

```
 x <- 1:10000
 set.seed(24)
 y <- sample(1:15000,10000,rep=TRUE)
 z <- sample(1:10000, 30000,rep=TRUE)
 akrun <- function(z,y,x) y[findInterval(z,x)]
 akrun2 <- function(z,y,x) y[fmatch(z,x)]

 carl<-function(z,y,x) unlist(sapply(z, function(j) y[which(j==x)]))
 marat<-function(z,y,x) y[match(z,x)]
 microbenchmark(carl(z,y,x),marat(z,y,x),
       akrun(z,y,x),akrun2(z,y,x), times=10, unit='relative')
 #Unit: relative
 #       expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq
 #  carl(z, y, x) 1997.57314 1997.697643 1902.240056 1857.202479 1894.021674
 # marat(z, y, x)    2.51456    2.491950    2.359782    2.070617    2.522286
 # akrun(z, y, x)    4.66293    4.497809    5.047581    4.782319    5.717679
 #akrun2(z, y, x)    1.00000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
  #        max neval cld
  # 1985.451747    10  b
  #    2.497346    10  a 
  #    5.723705    10  a 
  #    1.000000    10  a
```

Comment: Great.  Now I gotta use `cmpfun` on all the submissions to see which is really truly faster :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That would be perfect.